# In DNSSec, are Delegation Signer Records always SHA-1?

Tags: sha, threat-mitigation, configuration, dnssec, sha256

I'm creating a RSA/SHA-512 Zone Signing Key and Key Signing Key at Dynect Managed DNS (corporate offering)

The Delegation Signer Record that was created is SHA1.  Should I be concerned about this?

Comment: To the Thomas Pornin mobile!

Comment: The more I learn about DNSSec, the less I like it.  http://sockpuppet.org/blog/2015/01/15/against-dnssec/

Comment: LamonteCristo - I love DNSSEC (so I'm biased), and therefore would like to point out the opposing view: http://blog.easydns.org/2015/08/06/for-dnssec/

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, no, the DS records have many different possible algorithms. This list can be viewed [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/dns-sec-alg-numbers/dns-sec-alg-numbers.xhtml).

I'd recommend moving from SHA1 hashes to at least SHA256. Personally, I use ECDSAP384SHA384 (Algorithm number 14).